# Examples using 果てる

Tags: usage

The translation of this word is listed as:

> To end, to be finished, to be exhausted.

I am assuming these are in the order of importance or usage, But I could be wrong. I have searched for examples and the only examples that I can find are with the meaning "to be exhausted".   Is this the only way it is commonly used?

If it's also used as to end or to be finished I would like to see an example of it used in a sentence.   I have tried a few dictionaries but again the only words that come back relate to exhaustion i.e.: 疲れ果てる

Comment: What do you mean by "the translation" (shouldn't it be "a translation"?) or to say it another way where are you getting this definition?

Comment: [This link](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/jn/178007/meaning/m0u/) provides three different definitions: (1) to bring action to an end, (2) to die, (3) to completely do something.  And it provides example sentences.

Comment: Thanks  A.Ellett.  I think I know I understand the three meanings however  The first two:  to end and to die  seem pretty obscure and not something  that would be used a lot and every day language .    However when used with 疲れ果てる  it seems to be used a lot more .   I hate to waste time learning something that I will not use that often,  but it seems like 疲れはてる  is something to remember.   Does this make sense?

My mistake is probably assuming that the first two meanings defined in the dictionary are the most common ones

Comment: I guess the "exhausted" isn't tired exhausted but empty exhausted. Either way, using this word alone is pretty idiomatic today.

Answer (score 1):

In the form of 果てる itself, it's almost exclusively used in the meaning of to be exhausted, as you say, except a couple of literary expressions like 地平線の果てるところ (where the horizon ends). The other meanings are seen in some conjugated forms.

- 望みを果たす: to accomplish your wish
- 戦いの果て: consequence of battles